# Spring security session validate for each request

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring security 3.1 and I want to validate the session is invalid or not on each request/url. 
How I can do that?

I have implemented a concurrency filter and other required filters to do the authentication and all and its working fine.
I just want to check for each request if the session is invalid. If so, then I want to redirect it to a login page

Comment: If session is invalid, Spring Security will redirect to login page, no?

Comment: Yes but when you are using spring security session its working as you said but if you configure it with some other third party tool or something, then its hard to track the session is stiill valid. What exactly I am looking for the mechanism which will allow me to check the session is valid in the tool. The two things I am looking for 1. How to check the session with some third paty tool? 2. If session is invalid in the tool then how to redirect to login page?

Comment: Some third party tool? Your question is unclear.